# Block level helpers in Ruby on Rails for config file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I'm developing a website on RoR 3.1 with Ruby 1.9.
I would like to create a config file (RAILS_ROOT/config/roles.rb) for roles of users like that:

```
auth do
    roles :admin do
        auth_on :blogs, :to => [:create, update, :destroy]
        auth_on :comments, :to => [:create, update, :destroy]
    end

    roles :moderator do
        auth_on :blogs, :to => [update]
        auth_on :comments, :to => [:create, update] do
            where_attribute :user => current_user
        end
    end
end
```

The idea is to parse the file and set variables for roles. Do you have any idea how to implement this kind of helpers and how to parse a file block-by-block? If you have another idea to create a simple config file, just tell me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like you're trying to recreate the CanCan gem:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Using cancan you create an `ability.rb` file that specifies permissions. Here's an example:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your views (or controllers) you allow access like so:

```
<% if can? :update, @article %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article) %>
<% end %>
```

So rather than build something of your own, I'd recommend seeing if this will meet your needs first. If it doesn't, you may at least get some ideas on how to proceed with your ideas. Also, cancan works well with devise to provide overall authentication / authorization strategy.

Comment: Yes, you're right. In fact, I try to do something like "Declarative Authorization" gem [link](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization) that I already used. Even if CanCan and DA are great gems, I would like to try to do something myself using this kind of "block helpers". Thank for your help.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Best of luck with your project. (I'd appreciate an upvote or acceptance of my answer if you believe it was correct and helped you. Thanks -K )

Comment: Yes sure but I'm actually only have 6 reputation :(

Comment: lol thanks anyway. I gave you an upvote so you'll be there soon enough!

Answer (score 1):

why not to use YAML? something like

roles.yml:

```
roles:
  admin:
    blogs:
      create:
      update:
      destroy:
    comments:
      create:
      update:
```

and then something like

```
require 'yaml'
roles = YAML::load(File.open("roles.yml"))['roles']
roles.each do |user, role|
  role.each do |part,privs|
    privs.keys.each do |priv|
      setPrivilegeFor(user, part, priv)
    end 
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes it's a great solution that i already implement in another website. But I would like to try something else using only Ruby.Sorry, I forgot to mention. Btw, thank you !